# UIbutton on zooming UIImageView in Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am adding buttons as a subview to UIImageview in scrollview. When I am zooming UIImageView obviously those subview buttons get zoomed with the aspect ratio. I  don't want those buttons get zoomed. How can I achieve this. I have already tried to add the button on different view rather than adding it to the UIImageView but it will not maintain the proper x and y coordinates when we zoom image. Please provide me solution thanks in advance

Comment: Place your buttons on a view and add constraints.

Comment: I am not using autolayout for this application

Comment: then go for @Sanjay answer..it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this will involve a little mathematical intervention.

Use transform to zoom your image view.

```
[<yourview> setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(<xsacle>, <y scale>)];
```

Now this transform will also apply to all subviews you have to scale down the transform of your button appropriately.

```
[<Your Button> setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1/<xsacle>, 1/<y scale>)];
```

Now you need too adjust the x and y of button.

Answer (score 1):

U can set center of uibutton as a center of uiimageview like below (don't add button in imageview):

```
[btnControl setCenter:[imgView center]];
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to store your button frame;

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    initialButtonFrame = self.button.frame;
}
```

and use below code in `UIScrollView` delegate method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)sv
{

        self.button.frame = CGRectMake((initialButtonFrame.origin.x * self.scrollView.zoomScale),
                               (initialButtonFrame.origin.y * self.scrollView.zoomScale),
                               initialButtonFrame.size.width,
                               initialButtonFrame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: with your solution buttons remaining same size but x and y coordinates gets disturb. but I think this might help me need some mathematical calculations only.

Answer (score 0):

You should add those button as subview of some other view. Now add that other view and image view directly to scroll view. Now, you should implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` method.

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView
{
   return imageView;
}
```

This will zoom the imageview only and not the container view which has buttons as subviews.